# syntax highlighting in vim over ssh

Tags: ssh, vim, syntax-highlighting

When I ssh from work to the local network, I can turn syntax on in my vim instance and it works.  When I go home and ssh in, I turn on syntax highlighting and nothing happens.  While at home, if I use my local vim, I have syntax highlighting.

This leads me to believe it's something to do with ssh.  In my ssh session, folders still have a different color than files.

`echo $term` for work computer:

```
xterm-color
```

`echo $term` when ssh from work computer:

```
xterm-color
```

`echo $term` when ssh from home computer:

```
xterm
```

`echo $term` from home computer:

```
xterm
```

(will add the others when I get home)

**.vimrc:**

```
colorscheme elflord
set number
syntax on
```

Comment: `echo $TERM` and see what differs...

Comment: Post your `~/.vimrc` files.

Answer (score 2):

`xterm-color` is probably not a supported terminfo description on your work computers. You can verify this is the case by running `infocmp`. You'll likely get an error of `infocmp: couldn't open terminfo file`.

The fix for this is to set your `TERM` variable to something more common, for example just 'xterm' (in fact on my own system, the xterm terminfo description has more capabilities than the xterm-color description anyway).
I'm guessing you've got a bash profile/rc script which is setting this, as xterm does not set `TERM=xterm-color` by default. If so, just change it to `xterm` instead. If you don't have this set anywhere, just add `export TERM=xterm` to your `~/.bashrc` (this is assuming you're using bash).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  When I ssh from work, I get xterm-color on the remote machine.  When I xterm from home, I get xterm.  So I think xterm-color is supported and my home computer just isn't defaulting to xterm-color.

Comment: Ok, I tried the opposite of your suggestion.  I set my home computer to TERM=xterm-color and all is fine now!  Thanks for leading me to the answer!  If you edit your answer to reflect my modification to it, I will accept it.  Thanks again.